# Android QuickContactBadge arrow on ICS

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, quickcontactbadge

I'm developing an Android app containing a list view with a picture for each item.

I have set a `QuickContact` badge on each picture.

On android < ICS (android 4) the picture are displayed correctly, for example:

[quick contact badge ok on android<4](http://d.pr/i/X2Va)

But an Android ICS 4 or high, an arrow appears at the bottom right:

[quickcontact badge arrow on ics](http://d.pr/i/qg9V)

Is it possible to hide this bottom right arrow on quickcontact badge?

Answer (score 1):

This arrow is called the overlay and for Lollipop and above the following is the simplest way to hide it:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    contactBadge.setOverlay(null);
}
```

To support pre-Lollipop, I extend QuickContactBadge:

```
/**
 * Extend the QuickContactBadge to hide the overlay.
 */
public class MyQuickContactBadge extends QuickContactBadge {

    private static final String OVERLAY_FIELD_NAME = "mOverlay";

    public MyQuickContactBadge(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public MyQuickContactBadge(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyQuickContactBadge(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            super.setOverlay(null);
            return;
        }

        try {
            // Pre-lollipop we use reflection to null the overlay drawable
            Field overlayField = QuickContactBadge.class.getDeclaredField(OVERLAY_FIELD_NAME);

            // setAccessible(true) prevents IllegalAccessException
            overlayField.setAccessible(true);
            overlayField.set(this, null);

        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO: log exception
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not incorrect and this is by design. The purpose of QuickContactBadge is not just to display a picture, but to also provide an interface to bring up methods of contacting a contact based on an existing contact known by the system. The "arrow" is there to indicate to the user that by tapping the picture, they can get more information; it's like a bent corner of a page.

If you really want to use just a contact's picture, I believe you will need to use the ContactsContract APIs and gather the data yourself.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Instead of importing androids QuickContactBadge, use this code and import that as QuickContactBadge.

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */


import android.content.AsyncQueryHandler;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Intents;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.QuickContact;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.RawContacts;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Widget used to show an image with the standard QuickContact badge
 * and on-click behavior.
 */
public class OverlayLessQuickContactBadge extends ImageView implements OnClickListener {
    private Uri mContactUri;
    private String mContactEmail;
    private String mContactPhone;
    private Drawable mOverlay;
    private QueryHandler mQueryHandler;
    private Drawable mDefaultAvatar;
    private Context mContext = getContext();

    protected String[] mExcludeMimes = null;

    static final private int TOKEN_EMAIL_LOOKUP = 0;
    static final private int TOKEN_PHONE_LOOKUP = 1;
    static final private int TOKEN_EMAIL_LOOKUP_AND_TRIGGER = 2;
    static final private int TOKEN_PHONE_LOOKUP_AND_TRIGGER = 3;

    static final String[] EMAIL_LOOKUP_PROJECTION = new String[] {
        RawContacts.CONTACT_ID,
        Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
    };
    static final int EMAIL_ID_COLUMN_INDEX = 0;
    static final int EMAIL_LOOKUP_STRING_COLUMN_INDEX = 1;

    static final String[] PHONE_LOOKUP_PROJECTION = new String[] {
        PhoneLookup._ID,
        PhoneLookup.LOOKUP_KEY,
    };
    static final int PHONE_ID_COLUMN_INDEX = 0;
    static final int PHONE_LOOKUP_STRING_COLUMN_INDEX = 1;

    public OverlayLessQuickContactBadge(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public OverlayLessQuickContactBadge(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public OverlayLessQuickContactBadge(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        TypedArray styledAttributes = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Theme);


        mQueryHandler = new QueryHandler(mContext.getContentResolver());
        setOnClickListener(this);
    }



    /** This call has no effect anymore, as there is only one QuickContact mode */
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void setMode(int size) {
    }



    /** True if a contact, an email address or a phone number has been assigned */
    private boolean isAssigned() {
        return mContactUri != null || mContactEmail != null || mContactPhone != null;
    }

    /**
     * Resets the contact photo to the default state.
     */
    public void setImageToDefault() {
        if (mDefaultAvatar == null) {
            mDefaultAvatar = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture);
        }
        setImageDrawable(mDefaultAvatar);
    }

    /**
     * Assign the contact uri that this QuickContactBadge should be associated
     * with. Note that this is only used for displaying the QuickContact window and
     * won't bind the contact's photo for you. Call {@link #setImageDrawable(Drawable)} to set the
     * photo.
     *
     * @param contactUri Either a {@link Contacts#CONTENT_URI} or
     *            {@link Contacts#CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI} style URI.
     */
    public void assignContactUri(Uri contactUri) {
        mContactUri = contactUri;
        mContactEmail = null;
        mContactPhone = null;
        onContactUriChanged();
    }

    /**
     * Assign a contact based on an email address. This should only be used when
     * the contact's URI is not available, as an extra query will have to be
     * performed to lookup the URI based on the email.
     *
     * @param emailAddress The email address of the contact.
     * @param lazyLookup If this is true, the lookup query will not be performed
     * until this view is clicked.
     */
    public void assignContactFromEmail(String emailAddress, boolean lazyLookup) {
        mContactEmail = emailAddress;
        if (!lazyLookup) {
            mQueryHandler.startQuery(TOKEN_EMAIL_LOOKUP, null,
                    Uri.withAppendedPath(Email.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, Uri.encode(mContactEmail)),
                    EMAIL_LOOKUP_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
        } else {
            mContactUri = null;
            onContactUriChanged();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Assign a contact based on a phone number. This should only be used when
     * the contact's URI is not available, as an extra query will have to be
     * performed to lookup the URI based on the phone number.
     *
     * @param phoneNumber The phone number of the contact.
     * @param lazyLookup If this is true, the lookup query will not be performed
     * until this view is clicked.
     */
    public void assignContactFromPhone(String phoneNumber, boolean lazyLookup) {
        mContactPhone = phoneNumber;
        if (!lazyLookup) {
            mQueryHandler.startQuery(TOKEN_PHONE_LOOKUP, null,
                    Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, mContactPhone),
                    PHONE_LOOKUP_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
        } else {
            mContactUri = null;
            onContactUriChanged();
        }
    }

    private void onContactUriChanged() {
        setEnabled(isAssigned());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mContactUri != null) {
            QuickContact.showQuickContact(getContext(), OverlayLessQuickContactBadge.this, mContactUri,
                    QuickContact.MODE_LARGE, mExcludeMimes);
        } else if (mContactEmail != null) {
            mQueryHandler.startQuery(TOKEN_EMAIL_LOOKUP_AND_TRIGGER, mContactEmail,
                    Uri.withAppendedPath(Email.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, Uri.encode(mContactEmail)),
                    EMAIL_LOOKUP_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
        } else if (mContactPhone != null) {
            mQueryHandler.startQuery(TOKEN_PHONE_LOOKUP_AND_TRIGGER, mContactPhone,
                    Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, mContactPhone),
                    PHONE_LOOKUP_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
        } else {
            // If a contact hasn't been assigned, don't react to click.
            return;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set a list of specific MIME-types to exclude and not display. For
     * example, this can be used to hide the {@link Contacts#CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE}
     * profile icon.
     */
    public void setExcludeMimes(String[] excludeMimes) {
        mExcludeMimes = excludeMimes;
    }

    private class QueryHandler extends AsyncQueryHandler {

        public QueryHandler(ContentResolver cr) {
            super(cr);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onQueryComplete(int token, Object cookie, Cursor cursor) {
            Uri lookupUri = null;
            Uri createUri = null;
            boolean trigger = false;

            try {
                switch(token) {
                    case TOKEN_PHONE_LOOKUP_AND_TRIGGER:
                        trigger = true;
                        createUri = Uri.fromParts("tel", (String)cookie, null);

                        //$FALL-THROUGH$
                    case TOKEN_PHONE_LOOKUP: {
                        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            long contactId = cursor.getLong(PHONE_ID_COLUMN_INDEX);
                            String lookupKey = cursor.getString(PHONE_LOOKUP_STRING_COLUMN_INDEX);
                            lookupUri = Contacts.getLookupUri(contactId, lookupKey);
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                    case TOKEN_EMAIL_LOOKUP_AND_TRIGGER:
                        trigger = true;
                        createUri = Uri.fromParts("mailto", (String)cookie, null);

                        //$FALL-THROUGH$
                    case TOKEN_EMAIL_LOOKUP: {
                        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            long contactId = cursor.getLong(EMAIL_ID_COLUMN_INDEX);
                            String lookupKey = cursor.getString(EMAIL_LOOKUP_STRING_COLUMN_INDEX);
                            lookupUri = Contacts.getLookupUri(contactId, lookupKey);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }

            mContactUri = lookupUri;
            onContactUriChanged();

            if (trigger && lookupUri != null) {
                // Found contact, so trigger QuickContact
                QuickContact.showQuickContact(getContext(), OverlayLessQuickContactBadge.this, lookupUri,
                        QuickContact.MODE_LARGE, mExcludeMimes);
            } else if (createUri != null) {
                // Prompt user to add this person to contacts
                final Intent intent = new Intent(Intents.SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT, createUri);
                getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```